# How do I install the Pygraphics module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygraphics

I am trying to download the Pygraphics module using Python 2.7.6 and have been heretofore unsuccessful. Below I detail the steps I have taken so far. Any help with this would be most appreciated.

First, I tried the typical install using `pip`

`sudo pip install Pygraphics`

When I try to import the module, I receive an error saying `ImportError: No module named Pygraphics`.

To test whether the module was installed I ran the following code: `print sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])` which showed me all of my installed distributions.

This code returned the following list of all the distributions and clearly showed that Pygraphics is installed:

```
['altgraph==0.10.2', 'bdist-mpkg==0.5.0', 'bonjour-py==0.3', 'brewer2mpl==1.4', 'certifi==14.05.14',     'datetime==4.0.1', 'flask==0.10.1', 'ggplot==0.6.5', 'ipython==2.0.0-dev', 'itsdangerous==0.24', 'jdcal==1.0', 'jinja2==2.7.3', 'macholib==1.5.1', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'matplotlib==1.4.x', 'mock==1.0.1', 'modulegraph==0.10.4', 'nose==1.3.4', 'numpy==1.9.0.dev-297f54b', 'openpyxl==2.1.2', 'pandas==0.14.1', 'pandasql==0.6.1', 'patsy==0.3.0', 'pika==0.9.14', 'py2app==0.7.3', 'pygments==1.6', 'pygraphics==2.1']
```

After this, I tried using the GUI installer located on the following [Pygrahpics install website](https://code.google.com/p/pygraphics/downloads/list). While going through the installer, I received an error message saying "PyGraphics requires System Python 2.7 to install" despite the fact that I have downloaded Python 2.7.6.

At this point I don't know what to do and was hoping someone who may have had a similar issue might be able to help me out.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to use `import pygraphics`? I don't think that's how it works.

Comment: I think you can just do, for example, `import media`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've successfully install PyGraphics. Now `import picture` :)